# Pine editor script assistance

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to set make a pine script that plots the high and low of the first 8 hours of the week. Below is a link to a picture, the green and red dotted lines are from the script but they're not in the right place, i need them to match up with the white dotted lines but i'm not great with pine script and am struggling to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have also included the code below.

https://www.tradingview.com/x/nN1CKXyb/

```
study("Weekly Support & Resistance",overlay=true) 

highTimeFrame = input("4H", type=input.resolution)
sessSpec = input("2200-0600:12", type=input.session)

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

newbar = is_newbar("1440", sessSpec)

var float s1 = na
var float s2 = na
if newbar
    s1 := low
    s2 := high

plot(s1, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.red)
plot(s2, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.lime)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this script:

```
//@version=4
study("Test Script",overlay=true)

isNewPeriod(res) => change(time(res)) == 0 ? false : true
isNewWeek = isNewPeriod("1W")
var float upperLine = na
var float lowerLine = na

if isNewWeek[1]
    upperLine := max(high, high[1])
    lowerLine := min(low, low[1])

plot(upperLine, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.red)
plot(lowerLine, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, color=color.green)
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffDbY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcNkV.png)